# Inserting row into QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtsql, qsqltablemodel

When a row is going to be edited, an index is passed into the editing dialogue.
The edit works fine.
When I want to add a row, I don't pass an index to the dialogue constructor, so it knows that it's supposed to add a new row.
Here's the code of function reacting to dialogue's buttons

```
void DialogAddCl::on_buttonBox_clicked(QAbstractButton *button)
{
    // prepare
    m->database().transaction();
    QString debugstr;
    auto chi4 = ui->buttonBox->buttonRole(button);
    int rowCount = m->rowCount();
    switch (chi4) {
    case QDialogButtonBox::AcceptRole:
        if (!ind->isValid())
            // insert
            if (!m->insertRow(rowCount, *ind))
            {
                QMessageBox::critical (this, "Error inserting into model", m->lastError().text(), QMessageBox::Cancel);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                m->setData(m->index(rowCount, 0), rowCount+1);
            }
        else
        {
            // update
            rowCount = ind->row();
        }
        m->setData(m->index(rowCount, 1), ui->name->text());
        m->setData(m->index(rowCount, 2), ui->addr->text());
        // 12 other setData() calls

        if (m->submitAll())
        {
            m->database().commit();
        }
        else
        {
            // rollback if error
            m->database().rollback();
            debugstr = QString(m->database().lastError().text());
            QMessageBox::critical (this, "Database returned an error",
                                   m->database().lastError().text(), QMessageBox::Cancel);
        }
    case QDialogButtonBox::RejectRole:
        this->close();
        break;
    case QDialogButtonBox::ResetRole:
        fillFields();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Here's a piece of dialogaddcl.h:

```
private:
    Ui::DialogAddCl *ui;
    QSqlTableModel* m;
    QModelIndex* ind;
```

So, `m->submitAll()` works fine if I edit an existing record, and fails if I try to submit freshly inserted row. I have checked with debugging, `setData()` calls work fine even when adding, so it's not DB expecting `NOT NULL` fields and giving an error.
By the way, maybe somebody can point out a method to catch the actual error text? I tried with `debugstr`, but it always only contains empty string. So does the error message that I print

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To insert a row to `QSqlTableModel` you should not use `setData()` directly, if you must not use `insertRecord()`, where you indicate the row and the `QSqlRecord`. The `QSqlRecord` can be obtained through the `record()` method of the model.

```
InsertDialog dial;
if(dial.exec()== InsertDialog::Accepted){
    db.transaction();
    QString f = dial.firstname();
    QString l = dial.lastname();

    QSqlRecord record = model.record();
    /* since the id field has the autoincrement attribute,
     * it is not necessary to indicate its value,
     * that is because this field of the request is removed.
    */
    record.remove(record.indexOf("id"))
    record.setValue("firstname", f);
    record.setValue("lastname", l);
    /*-1 is set to indicate that it will be added to the last row*/
    if(model.insertRecord(-1, record)){
        qDebug()<<"successful insertion";
        model->submitAll();
    }
    else{
        db.rollback();
    }
}
```

<sup>In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/47318601) you will find an example.</sup>

Comment: wait, but I didn't use setData to insert, I used it to set the values in a freshly inserted row. I call insertRow before setData

Comment: if it's impossible to use insertRow(s) however, I fully accept that. Just give any link to prove that and I'll switch to using insertRecord

Comment: Is that you do not have to use setData not insertRow, you just have to use insertRecord, this method calls the previous ones internally.

Comment: I see now. I don't need to delete ID however, since it's not auto incremented. I wil lchange that detail. Thank you for clarification of what-calls-what

Comment: @mekkanizer Okay, in my case if I did it, it was just a plus. :P

Comment: Don't forget to submit: `if(model.insertRecord(-1, record)){
        model->submitAll();
    }`, otherwise the changes will not be saved.